# Extract groups with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `table`
    (`source` varchar(20), `eventid` varchar(9), `system` varchar(10),`accountname` varchar(10)) 
;

INSERT INTO `table`
    (`source`, `eventid`, `system` ,`accountname`)
VALUES
    ('uatapp', '528', 'bxw','jbb'),
    ('uatapp', '528', 'bxw','jbc'),
    ('nxapp', '530', 'gg','ff'),
    ('aaunswh20', '528', 'ccd','ff'),
    ('172.1.12.3', '528','vv','ff'),   
        ('172.1.12.3', '528', 'vv', 'ff'),
    ('172.1.12.3', '528','vv','ff3')
;
```

If I use the query

```
SELECT   SOURCE,accountname,SYSTEM, count(*)
FROM     `table`
WHERE    eventid = '528'
GROUP BY SOURCE,accountname
```

I get the result

```
SOURCE  ACCOUNTNAME     SYSTEM  COUNT(*)
172.1.12.3  ff  vv  2
172.1.12.3  ff3     vv  1
aaunswh20   ff  ccd     1
uatapp  jbb     bxw     1
uatapp  jbc     bxw     1
```

I would like the result to show only

```
SOURCE  ACCOUNTNAME     SYSTEM  COUNT(*)
172.1.12.3  ff  vv  2
172.1.12.3  ff3     vv  1
uatapp  jbb     bxw     1
uatapp  jbc     bxw     1
```

(ie) grouping of source,accountname with multiple rows and not a single row such as AAUNSWH20.

Can somebody help in formulating the query?..thanks

Comment: What DBMS is this in? Kinda important. Maybe mysql? Ahhh, it has to be, given your `GROUP BY` doesn't include `SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query you were probably rejecting is one that properly shows the source and system, but doesn't group by `accountname`:

```
SELECT source, system
FROM `table`
WHERE eventid = '528'
GROUP BY source, system
HAVING Count(DISTINCT accountname) >= 2;
```

The problem with this is, then you can't see what account names were used. This can be accomplished by putting this query into a derived table, with a join back to the original table, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   T.*
FROM
   `table` T
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT source, system
      FROM `table`
      WHERE eventid = '528'
      GROUP BY source, system
      HAVING Count(DISTINCT accountname) >= 2
   ) D ON T.source = D.source
      AND T.system = D.system
WHERE
   T.eventid = '528'
;
```

See this working [in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61e3d/1).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
SELECT   SOURCE,accountname,SYSTEM, count(*)
FROM     [table] a
WHERE    eventid = '528'
and exists (select source, COUNT(*) from [table] b
            where a.eventid = b.eventid
            and a.source = b.source
            group by source
            having COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY SOURCE,system,accountname
```

Anyway, `table` is reserved keyword, so use `[]` in your query.